# Try to understand the definition of the property $D$ in one paper of J.E.Vaughan's

Tags: general-topology

**Try to understand the definition of the property $D$ in [one paper of J.E.Vaughan's](http://www.topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v03/tp03120.pdf)**

Firstly, let us see the Definitions(see page 238 of the paper):

> A  countably  infinite discrete set $A \subset  X$
>   has  property  $D$  in $X$  provided  there exists a  discrete family 
>   of open sets $\{U_a :  a \in A\}$ such that $U_a \cap A = \{a\} $ for all $a\in  A$.

and

> A  space  $X $ is said to have  property  $D$  provided  that every countably  infinite discrete set in $X$  has  property $D$    in $X$.

And in the page 239 of this paper, the author said that a 
regular space $X$ has  property $D$  if and  only  if every  pair of disjoint closed sets,  one  of which  is a  discrete sequence,  can be  separated by  disjoint open  sets.

However, as we know, in the regular space, any countable discrete subspace is [strongly discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222560/how-to-show-any-convergent-sequence-is-strongly-discrete-in-hausdorff-space). So, my question is this:

> Is any regular space has property $D$?

(Therefore we can omit the condition that "every  pair of disjoint closed sets,  one  of which  is a  discrete sequence,  can be  separated by  disjoint open  sets. ")

Thanks for any help and any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when Jerry says *discrete set*, he means *closed, discrete set*. (He makes this clear just before Definition 1.) Similarly, when he says that the family $\{U_a:a\in A\}$ is discrete, he means that it’s pairwise disjoint **and locally finite**. The [deleted Tikhonov plank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_plank) is an example of a $T_3$-space that is not a $D$-space: the set $\{\omega_1\}\times\omega$ is a closed, discrete set, but if $U_n$ is an open nbhd of $\langle\omega_1,n\rangle$ for $n\in\omega$, every open nbhd of $\langle\alpha,\omega\rangle$ meets infinitely many of the $U_n$’s for every sufficiently large $\alpha<\omega_1$.